# Calculate total number of minutes in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am a fairly beginner user of PowerBI and still learning the ropes about DAX / PowerQuery. I have a column called "Time Usage" that has the time in text format:  "1d 10h 25min", "2h 1d 30min", "5m 2h 3d" - a bit inconsistent.

What is the best way to calculate the total number of minutes? One solution I can think of is splitting the column in PowerQuery by a space delimiter and using nested IF/SWITCH statements in DAX, however this seems inefficient.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new Custom Column, and enter this formula:

```
let
  txt = " " & [Time Usage] & " ",
  dd = Text.Select(List.Last(Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(txt, " ", "d"), " ")), {"0".."9"}),
  hh = Text.Select(List.Last(Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(txt, " ", "h"), " ")), {"0".."9"}),
  mm = Text.Select(List.Last(Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(txt, " ", "m"), " ")), {"0".."9"}),
  ss = Text.Select(List.Last(Text.Split(Text.BetweenDelimiters(txt, " ", "s"), " ")), {"0".."9"}),
  dur = #duration(Number.From(dd)??0, Number.From(hh)??0, Number.From(mm)??0, Number.From(ss)??0),
  tm = Duration.TotalMinutes(dur)
in
  tm
```

This will support days, hours, minutes, and seconds - provided in full
or in parts, and in any order.

[image]

Comment: @user15180012 - Any follow-up? Otherwise please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with Davide, your first problem is getting the inconsistent formatting of the text into a more usable form.

The technique I used was to first ensure everything was in lower case and to grab a copy of the original column.

I then split that column by spaces.

Each of those resulting columns I then split by digit to non-digit

I then add three custom columns which contain only the first character of each of the "periods" - i.e. "min" becomes "m"

I then reconstructed the data into period + number and unpivoted on those 3 columns

This gave me 3 rows for each of the the original items, each row only containing the day or hour or minutes value

I then split that column by non-digit to digit

Pivoted on Value.1 - the d, h or m giving me the original value with the number of days, hours and minutes in their own columns

From there you can create a Duration or calculate the minutes

I'm not sure all the reconstuction is actually necessary so some tidying up could be done, but here is the M for it

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Time"]}[Content],
    #"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Time usuage", Text.Lower, type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Lowercased Text", "Original", each [Time usuage]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom", "Time usuage", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Time usuage.1", "Time usuage.2", "Time usuage.3"}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Time usuage.1", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)), {"Time usuage.1.1", "Time usuage.1.2"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Character Transition", "Custom1", each Text.Start([Time usuage.1.2],1)),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Time usuage.2", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)), {"Time usuage.2.1", "Time usuage.2.2"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Character Transition1", "Custom2", each Text.Start([Time usuage.2.2],1)),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Time usuage.3", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)), {"Time usuage.3.1", "Time usuage.3.2"}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Character Transition2", "Custom3", each Text.Start([Time usuage.3.2],1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Time usuage.1.2", "Time usuage.2.2", "Time usuage.3.2"}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Reconstructed1", each [Custom1] & [Time usuage.1.1]),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Reconstructed2", each [Custom2] & [Time usuage.2.1]),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom5", "Reconstructed3", each [Custom3] & [Time usuage.3.1]),
    #"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Added Custom6", {"Reconstructed1", "Reconstructed2", "Reconstructed3"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns",{"Original", "Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Character Transition3", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Character Transition3"[Value.1]), "Value.1", "Value.2", List.Max),
    #"Added Custom8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Duration", each Duration.From([d] & "." & [h] & ":" & [m])),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom8",{{"d", Int64.Type}, {"h", Int64.Type}, {"m", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TimeInMinutes", each (60 * 24 * [d]) + (60 * [h]) + [m])
in
    #"Added Custom7"
```